# Error Reading from Database on Moodle Test Site Copy

Tags: moodle

I'm facing a problem with my Moodle test site and would appreciate any help. Below are the details:

Background:

Created a copy of my Moodle site (version 4.0.1+) for upgrade testing.
This method was previously successful with the same version of Moodle.
I have backups and full server access (VPS).
The main Moodle site is running without issues.
Issue:

Experiencing an "error reading from database" on the test site.
With debugging code in the Config.php file the error code is

```
"Error
Table "sessions" does not exist
     Debug info:
    Error code: ddltablenotexist
    Stack trace:
    line 665 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: dml_exception thrown
    line 1621 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->where_clause()
    line 425 of /lib/classes/session/manager.php: call to moodle_database->get_record()
    line 165 of /lib/classes/session/manager.php: call to       core\session\manager::initialise_user_session()
    line 139 of /lib/classes/session/manager.php: call to core\session\manager::start_session()
    line 829 of /lib/setup.php: call to core\session\manager::start()
    line 28 of /config.php: call to require_once()
    line 30 of /index.php: call to require_once()"


Configurations in config.php seem correct.
Server details include:

cPanel Version: 110.0 (build 17)
Apache Version: 2.4.58
MySQL Version: 10.6.16-MariaDB
OS: Linux (3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64)
```

Increased server size and space, expecting this would prevent any resource-related issues.
Transferred files manually via FTP, as this worked in the past.
Attempted to chmod the moodledata folder for proper permissions, but the exact commands I used previously are unclear. I was expecting this to resolve any access issues with the database.
I expected these steps to replicate my previous successful setup, but instead, I encountered the database error.
Constraints:

Time pressure due to an upcoming upgrade and personal commitments.
Limited experience with Git; seeking a solution that doesn't involve learning it right now.

Questions:

How can I fix the "error reading from database" issue on my Moodle test site?
What is the correct command for chmoding  the moodledata folder to ensure functionality? I know they should be 777 but I am unable to find instructions that work for me for changing them in terminal. I did it in October and was very proud of myself but with the personal family pressures my brain is not functioning in the usual "fun from learning" way it usually does.
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I need to get this test site operational for upgrade practice soon.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix might be to switch off database sessions in `config.php` on your test site

```
$CFG->dbsessions = 0;
```

This will store sessions in files rather than the database

You can check how sessions are stored on the production site via

Site admin > Server > Server > Session Handling

"Use database for session information" - dbsessions

Sessions can be stored in the database, files or memcache

See https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/Session_handling